# Parse a text string into fields based on text and position VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a .text file of strings delimited by spaces. That would be the obvious parsing solution when I bring it into Excel or Access, but since the strings are not the same size, the fields will be incorrect. I'm hoping to find some help here as I'm not really experienced with this.

This is an example section of the string:

259998887575 15 ***00:14:38*** C33 ***0:14:42*** T33 ***00:14:52 00:14:58***

202224446898 33 ***00:16:24*** B23 00:17:00 C31 ***00:17:15*** T31 00:19:30 C04 00:17:15 T28 ***00:19:30 00:19:32***

The numbers with colons are time stamps and the letter codes (T/C/B) all represent a different field type. My problem is that there can be any number of C and T time stamps listed in the string and there may or may not be a B time stamp.

I'd like the result to show 4 fields... the first, the first c time stamp, the last t time stamp and the last time stamp (the bolded time stamps). All other information can be disregarded. I'd like to use VB to cycle through due to the number of records.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you'd manually convert those two records into the format you're looking for, including the field names you'd like to use.  Once you've done that, I can help you with parsing.

Comment: Never mind ... looks as if @jens is not as crosseyed as I am.

Comment: We'll see if that is what OP wants, it's not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems like you want to split the dates into types, determined by the bit before each letter.
You can use the Strings.Split method to divide the lines at the spaces. Then use the Date.TryParse method to check which parts are Dates (or times, it's the same). Then you select the first letter of the previous part and sort the dates into their respective lists.

```
    Dim s As String = "202224446898 33 00:16:24 B23 00:17:00 C31 00:17:15 T31 00:19:30 C04 00:17:15 T28 00:19:30 00:19:32"
    Dim parts() As String = Strings.Split(s, " ") 'Split the string at all spaces

    'Create lists of Date, one list for all dates, one list for each Letter
    Dim Tdates As New List(Of Date) 'This stores converted dates
    Dim Cdates As New List(Of Date) 'This stores converted dates
    Dim Bdates As New List(Of Date) 'This stores converted dates
    Dim Alldates As New List(Of Date) 'This stores converted dates

    For i = 0 To parts.Count - 1 'Iterate through all parts
        Dim ThisDate As Date
        If Date.TryParse(parts(i), ThisDate) = True Then 'This tries to parse the current part as a date, returns True if the part is a date
            Alldates.Add(ThisDate) 'You want to store all dates in this list
            If i > 0 AndAlso parts(i - 1).Length > 0 Then
                Dim PrevPartsFirstLetter As String = parts(i - 1)(0) 'Crop the first letter of the previous part
                Select Case PrevPartsFirstLetter
                    Case "T" : Tdates.Add(ThisDate)
                    Case "C" : Cdates.Add(ThisDate)
                    Case "B" : Bdates.Add(ThisDate)
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'You can now select the parts you want from the lists
```

The Tdates-List contains all dates which have a T thing before them and so on. The AllDates-List contains all dates in the line.